# Session timeouts

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

setting the timeout for a site vie the web.config to 60 minutes.

```
<SessionState mode="stateServer" ....... timeout="60">
```

***how is this different then setting the timeout vie IIS 6.0??***

Right click on website 
go to properties
click on website tabe
connections section -> connection timeout: XXXXXX?

***If a set a different value in the web.config vrs IIS which value would be overriden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two things are totally different, Connection timeout is the maximum time a connection can be kept open before it is terminated.

A [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) timeout is the amount of time a session is kept alive before it is abandoned.

**Update as requested**

I think the OP is refering to `Connection Timeout` as in this image, rather than the classic asp session timout that is refered to in your link, this is how long a connection to the server wll be kept open, or another way of thinkning about it would be how long a request is allowed to take to execute..

[image]

Comment: according to the links i Posted below the connection timeout is only used for classic asp. Can you explain what a connection timeout entails? thank you

Comment: Thank you very much in clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

[IIS Session Timeout vs ASP.NET Session Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544500/iis-session-timeout-vs-asp-net-session-timeout)

[Session timeout in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net)

Duplicated answers