# ASP.NET MVC Getting Error 504 after 10 minutes of File Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

I have an ASP.NET MVC2 Web application, working with SQL Server 2008 R2, managed by IIS 6.2. I have a functionality where one particular admin needs to upload about 5000 documents, which then get to be processed and stored in the server, while their names are saved in a database.

Problem is, on the client side, 10 minutes after the file upload begins, I get:

504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.

I changed the httpRuntime.ExecutionTimeout in the web.config but it didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone know where is the value limiting me stored?

Here's my [web.config file](http://pastebin.com/VXs0BFTp)

EDIT: Also, after the Error 504 is received, the data storage in the database keeps going anyways.

Comment: Could it be that your DB connection time out? Can you log your error on server side with full stacktrace?

Comment: Gonna try to do the upload from the server, see what it returns and edit the question telling what happened.

Comment: Did you also set: `maxRequestLength`?  And what value did you put in for `executionTimeout`?  (It's in seconds I believe)

Comment: Also, you can try ask same question here with configs, could that's administatrive issue http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @teovankot I'm currently unable to try this directly in the server but however managed to add a copy of the web.config.

Comment: @ebyrob this is my httpRuntime line: <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="4000200" executionTimeout="14400" />

Comment: 4 hours and 40 gigs seem like enough memory and time for the request.  There is also the session timeout configured in iis manager, but that usually defaults to 20 minutes not 10 minutes (actually in iis 6 it was 10 minutes...). see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544500/iis-session-timeout-vs-asp-net-session-timeout

Comment: According to that, I should change my sessionState value in the web.config file, but i changed it to 2 and got the same error after the same amount of time.

Comment: Hi Santlev, did you get a solution for this? I am facing exactly the same issue.